# Run Stored Procedure via Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, service-broker

I would like to execute stored procedures in parallel in SQL Server 2014. I decided to take the approach mentioned in rusanu's blog (http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) and tried to go with Service broker.

Now to the parallel execution - I have set MAX_QUEUE_READERS to 5 and tried to execute several long running procedures. I also used ALTER DATABASE XXX SET ENABLE_BROKER to enable the service broker. However the stored procedure `usp_AsyncExecInvoke` creates a message but does not execute the `usp_AsyncExecActivated` stored procedure via the queue.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Service Broker setup is quite complex and omitting any one thing can prevent it working. Make sure that you didn't miss anything while creating the SSB infrastructure.

Comment: Look at sys.service_queues for all of the activation stuff. Like: is it on, how many queue readers are there, etc.

Comment: Check `sys.transmission_queue` in the DB from where you're issuing the `SEND`. Tell us how many rows, and what the `transmission_status` column says

Comment: @RemusRusanu I am having the same issue. I checked sys.transmission_queue. It is empty. The stored procedures I am running are also CLR ones. Are you aware of any limitations regarding that?

Comment: I am also using this version of the code. http://rusanu.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-to-a-background-procedure/

Comment: Never mind, that was my bad. The CLR code I wrote was going into an infinite loop and I did not realize the start time is updated when the execution is complete which is a bit odd but anyway. It is working.

Comment: One other question though :) how can I kill the running backgourn procedures?